# How to interpret PosgreSQL txid_current() value

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I have the below psql statements:

Assumption :initial txid: a

```
select txid_current();
----------------------
a+1

begin;
insert into tab( v1,v2);
insert into tab (v3,v4);
commit;

select txid_current();
----------------------
a+3
```

Why do I see the transaction ID as a+3 shouldn't it be a+2?

How does txid_current work?

Is there any effective way where I could only return the current txid without the additional increment ?

Comment: There's three transactions here; the implicit one where you select `txid_current` the first time, the explicit one where you insert the data, and the implicit one you select the `txid_current` the second time.

Comment: But select isn't supposed to be a transaction right ? Also what happens when there's a select txid_current  between the begin and commit? How does this function work

Comment: Yes, select needs to be in a (read-only) transaction. If you don't do it yourself, postgres does it for you.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you were trying to state ....

Comment: If you execute `SELECT` without a `BEGIN`, then PostgreSQL implicitly begins a transaction before and commits after executing the `SELECT`. Same with insert, update, delete, and probably many others. Many RDBMS' do this; it's called autocommit mode.

Comment: If that's the case what happens (assume st with txid a)if you a select current_txid and then do select *from table;select* from table; select current txid.would txid be a+4?

Comment: Maybe. It might be more if other connections begin transactions in the meantime, or less if the database was vacuumed in the meantime.

Comment: What if there's a test data base and only one user works on it and only on a single table say tab.He/She is using the above statements against it

Comment: I tried with a single db working on a single table .However I see the result as a+2 instead of a+4... It seems something with the function

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Key points to understand:

- *Everything* is in a transaction. If you don't explicitly create one with `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`) one is created for you just for that statement.
- Read-only `SELECT`s don't get a full transaction ID, they only get a virtual transaction ID. So even though it's a transaction, `SELECT 1;` or whatever doesn't increment the transaction ID counter.
- Calling `txid_current()` *forces* the allocation of a transaction ID if one wasn't already allocated. So a read-only transaction will now have a transaction ID, where it previously wouldn't.

Of course, txids are also allocated across sessions. In practice your example above might get txid's of a+1 and a+429 if the database is busy.

It's generally not wise to use the transaction ID for anything at the application level. In particular:

Treat `xmin` and `xmax` as internal system level fields, and treat the result of `txid_current()` as a meaningless numeric value.

### Details on correct and incorrect uses for xids

In particular you should never:

- Compare xids by numeric value to draw any sort of conclusion about their ordering;
- Add or subtract transaction IDs;
- Sort transaction IDs;
- Increment or decrement transaction IDs
- Compare a 32-bit `xid` typed field with a 64-bit `bigint` epoch-extended xid, even for equality.

So from an application perspective xids are neither monotonic nor ordinal.

You *can* safely:

- compare two 64-bit epoch-extended xids for equality or inequality; and
- pass xids to `txid_status(...)` and other functions documented as taking an xid

Beware: PostgreSQL uses 32-bit narrow xids like the `xid` type, and 64-bit epoch-extended xids typically represented as `bigint` like those returned by `txid_current()`. Comparing these for equality will generally seem to work on a new database install, but once the first epoch wraparound has occurred and they'll no longer be equal. Pg doesn't even give you an easy way to see the xid epoch at the SQL level; you have to:

```
select (txid_current() >> 32) AS xid_epoch;
```

to get the upper 32 bits of the epoch-extended xid reported by `txid_current()`.

So ... whatever you are trying to do, it's likely that the transaction ID is not the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much! this has by far been the most clear and simple explanation I'v seen.I'v understood now as to why I see a +1 .... once again thanks so much !! :)

Comment: @MissJ. Thanks. I appreciate that, as I've worked hard to learn to write more clearly and less verbosely.

Comment: A few situations in which using `txid` at the application level makes sence: 1) when resting an application-level class that manages transactions; 2) when doing a non-trivial export/import in a single transaction and asserting that no code accidentally commits it (this can be done by comparing `txid`s).

Comment: Strongly disagree that txid_current() isn't for application use: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-10-transaction-traceability/

Comment: @drrob Hilarious. I wrote that. You are correct that using the xid as an argument to `txid_status()` is appropriate, though that patch didn't exist when I wrote this answer. There are other cases too, but they are infrequent. And when you do use xids you should generally treat them as opaque values, *without* assuming ordinality or monotonicity. Don't compare them except for equality. And even then it's hairy because PostgreSQL uses 32-bit short xids in some places and 64-bit epoch-extended xids in other places...

Comment: @drrob I've edited the answer. Let me know if that covers it better.

Comment: Woo! That is comical! Well the answer has benefited greatly so it was worth the embarrassment on my part!!! Completely see what you are getting at now so thanks for the update and all the best!